# How to let program know that object of parent class is also object of child class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a parent abstract class that has some field, and I also have a child class that has an additional field. There is a method that takes the object of a parent class as input, but if I give it a child class object I need to use its field too. If I do this directly it would give an error.

I couldn't find a way to access a child's field and the only way worked without making a child's field parent was making an array of every field of an object.

```cs
public abstract class Parent 
{
    public int ParentIntField;
    public void ParentMethod(Parent other) 
    {
        if (other is Child) 
        {
            int x = other.ChildIntField;
            //do some job with other.ChildIntField
        }
        //maybe do some job with other.ParentIntField
    }
}
public class Child: Parent
{
    public int ChildIntField;
}
```

P.s I'm very new to c# and also my English might be bad, sorry.

Comment: You will have to cast the object. But more importantly, I think you are making a Liskov substitution violation and you probably should rethink your design.

Comment: Use `(other is Child child)`. Adding a variable name after the `is Child` wil allow you to use that casted variable directly. You can then access `child.ChildIntField`. That's just a plain solution for what you're trying to do. There is a cast and the logic seems to be flawed so I would suggest you to rethink your Design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you could do:

#### [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) the Object

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public int ParentIntField;
    public void ParentMethod(Parent other)
    {
        if (other is Child) /// Can do: (other is Child child) to avoid manually casting
        {
            Child childObject = (Child)other; // We are casting the object here.

            int x = childObject.ChildIntField;
            //do some job with other.ChildIntField
        }
        //maybe do some job with other.ParentIntField
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public int ChildIntField;
}
```

#### But Consider Rethinking your design:

But I would rethink your design, because you are entering into a [Liskov substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violation here.

Here is an attempt at re-design. You don't need to pass the parent object into the method providing you are only accessing the variables associated with that particular instance. If you want to access another Parent object, then you will have to add the Parent parameter back into the method.

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public int ParentIntField;

    virtual public void Manipulate()
    {            
        //maybe do some job with other.ParentIntField
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public int ChildIntField;

    public override void Manipulate()
    {
        int x = ChildIntField; //do some job with ChildIntField            

        base.Manipulate();
    }
}
```

Comment: an example with `override` that calls `base` method might encourage op to rethink the design.

Comment: You can also use `(other is Child child)` instead of casting manually.

Comment: @BagusTesa i use different code depending on type of input(other) not type of object

Comment: @Rwarazor "i use different code depending on type of input(other) not type of object" ---> this is a liskov substitution violation. I strongly recommend you rethink your code design. That logic should be held within the classes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Being an abstract class, you would want to avoid handling the child object instances. like the previous answers, try to override that method in the child and you can invoke the base class functionality using the "base" keyword. In VS, when you override, it would automatically inject that base invocation as default syntax.

Comment: the problem was that i need to use different code depending on type of input not type of object from what we call method